# how do i unhide the run and debug button in the place where the open editors are in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]I accidently hid the button and I want to know how to unhide it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using **Python** extensions? Please show your interface and *user* and *workspace* settings.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click the button in your picture, then choose **Run Code**(or **Run Python File** or **Run or Debug...**)

[image]

Comment: thank you very muck for fixing my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Right click the three dots on the top right of your screen and click the "Run or Debug..." option:
[image: Option Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Activity Bar then select Run And Debug. If you do not have the Activity Bar, it is under View>Appearance>Activity Bar.

You can also do ctrl+shift+d.

A third way is through the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) then search View: Show Run And Debug.

Comment: not the activity bar you know in python in the top right corner the play button i hid

Comment: @Kleb-wants-subs Use VScode command `View: Show Run And Debug` should work.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT not the activity bar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the *Code Runner*, add the following setting to show the run button.

```
    "code-runner.showRunIconInEditorTitleMenu": true,
```

If you are using the **Python** extension, [Guillaume G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76735751/19133920) is correct, right click on the red line area of the image, and select `Run or Debug...`.

[image]